# ng expression not working in bootstrap modal title

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, handsontable

I have an bootstrap model where for the title I want to use ng-expression. Binding is happening, but not on initial load. Ill have to click on any textbox or dropdown in the modal for the ng-expression to load on title.

HTML tag

```
<h4 class="modal-title"><b>Feedback for - {{Name}} </b></h4>
```

Modal does not open on click of any button in HTML,it opens on click of cell in handsontable.

Handsontable code:

```
HOT.addHook('afterOnCellMouseDown', function (event, coords, TD) {/*Pop-up event*/
    if ((coords.col == 11 && TD.innerHTML != '') || TD.innerHTML == undefined) {
        $scope.Name="Name";
        $("#modal").modal("show");
    }
});
```

What could be the issue? Any way to re render the modal?

Comment: When you mix Angular and Jquery, angular has problems watching the variable changes. If you use the modal of angular bootstrap it should work fine.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Try adding $scope.$apply() at the last of if statement. Should work

Comment: @RahulArora.. Thanks,it works... :D